# SQL Server Express not connecting with mssql typescript

Tags: sql-server, database, typescript, api

I've been trying to connect to my database via mssql in a typescript API. This is the part of my code:

```
const db = require('mssql');
try{
     db.connect('mssql://user:password@LAPTOP-xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS/Database?encrypt=true');
     //Server name: LAPTOP-xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS
     console.log('DB is connected');
}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
export default db;
```

I've tried just putting the server name in multiple ways: LAPTOP-xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS, LAPTOP-xxxxx, SQLEXPRESS, localhost and 10.73.82.85 but none of the works. This is the error that gives me:

[image]

If anyone has the answer for this would be very helpful. Usually the code above works but I am working on a different computer and this wont let me connect. Thank you!

Comment: Please post errors as text not images.

Comment: First confirm that you can connect through a database tool such as SSMS

Comment: Is TCP/IP enabled for your express server instance? Can you ping the machine name? Note that your image contains the actual machine name and defeats your obfuscation attempt.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You must escape the backslash in your connectstring.
db.connect('mssql://user:password@LAPTOP-xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS/Database?encrypt=true')</strike>

Ah sorry, I'm not using URI connection string but the classic connection string, where you have to use `server\instance`.

For a uri connectstring, according to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#formats), you have to use a forward slash `/` instead of a backslash `\` to separate server and instance

```
mssql://username:password@server/INSTANCE/database?....
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it gives me an invalid url error. In the other type it says that it could not connect to the database.